# Redshift having query with count function not working as expected

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

This is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "student_id" 
FROM "school_1__im_student_model"."students"
GROUP BY "student_id"
HAVING COUNT("age") >= '2'
```

The result is

```
| "student_id" |
| 1000         |
| 1111         |
```

I need to get the total count for this query.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "student_id") 
FROM "school_1__im_student_model"."students"
GROUP BY "student_id"
HAVING COUNT("age") >= '2'
```

But with this query, I get values like this:

```
|count|
| 1   |
| 1   |
```

but I need to get total records. ex - 2

Answer (score 1):

The "having" command is executed after the `COUNT(DISTINCT "student_id")`, you should use subqueries to build the result that you want step by step.

Something like

```sql
-- create
CREATE TABLE ROOM_STUDENT (
  room_id INTEGER,
  student_id INTEGER,
  age INTEGER
);

-- insert
INSERT INTO ROOM_STUDENT VALUES (1, 10001, 22);
INSERT INTO ROOM_STUDENT VALUES (1, 10002, 23);
INSERT INTO ROOM_STUDENT VALUES (1, 10003, 23);
INSERT INTO ROOM_STUDENT VALUES (2, 10001, 22);
INSERT INTO ROOM_STUDENT VALUES (2, 10002, 23);
INSERT INTO ROOM_STUDENT VALUES (3, 10002, 23);
INSERT INTO ROOM_STUDENT VALUES (3, 10003, 24);

with sub as (
  SELECT student_id, count(*) as count_rooms FROM ROOM_STUDENT WHERE age > 22 group by student_id
)
select count(*) as count_students from sub where count_rooms > 2;
```

You can see it running here https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3y28krk5u

Here is a link teaching more about the "with" command in SQL [https://modern-sql.com/feature/with#:~:text=Syntax&text=The%20syntax%20after%20the%20keyword,query%E2%80%94again%20in%20parentheses](https://modern-sql.com/feature/with#:%7E:text=Syntax&text=The%20syntax%20after%20the%20keyword,query%E2%80%94again%20in%20parentheses).